# Display empty custom taxonomies differently than with one with posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to display all of my custom taxonomies using get_terms. This part is fine.  But I'd like to display the taxonomies that have zero posts attached to them slightly differently.

Here's what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/k6sGXk0V

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Many thanks,
Mitch

Comment: Please post your code in your question

Answer (score 1):

The number of posts attached can be found here: `$term->count`.

So you could do the following:

```
$class_empty_term = '';
if( $term->count == 0 )
    $class_empty_term = 'empty';
$term_list .= '<div class="' . $class_empty_term . ' grid__item ...">';
$term_list .= '<div class="panel text--center">';
```